# PHP - Multidimensional Array to Json

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is a bit of a reverse engineering question, but I want to know how to write in PHP a proper multidimensional array in PHP that outputs the following javascript array.

```
      [
        {
          "key": "Basic Planners",
          "values": [{"x": "YourPhone","y": 150}, 
                     {"x": "Universe X3","y": 300},
                     {"x": "ePhone 74s","y": 1500}, 
                     {"x": "NextUs","y": 50}, 
                     {"x": "Humanoid","y": 500
                    }]
        }, {
          "key": "No-Namers",
          "values": [{"x": "YourPhone","y": 300}, 
                     {"x": "Universe X3","y": 250}, 
                     {"x": "ePhone 74s","y": 400}, 
                     {"x": "NextUs","y": 150}, 
                     {"x": "Humanoid","y": 900}]

        }, {
          "key": "Feature Followers",
          "values": [{"x": "YourPhone","y": 350}, 
                     {"x": "Universe X3","y": 900}, 
                     {"x": "ePhone 74s","y": 100}, 
                     {"x": "NextUs","y": 500}, 
                     {"x": "Humanoid","y": 250}]

        }, {
          "key": "Hipsters & Elites",
          "values": [{"x": "YourPhone","y": 200}, 
                     {"x": "Universe X3","y": 350}, 
                     {"x": "ePhone 74s","y": 50}, 
                     {"x": "NextUs","y": 800}, 
                     {"x": "Humanoid","y": 100}]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: It's a little amusing that instead of having a key called "Basic Planners" you have a key called "key" with a value of "Basic Planners".  It would make the structure a lot more compact to use `{"Basic Planners": [{"x":...},...], "Feature Followers":[...]` etc

Comment: Good point. I was using the format for an nvd3.js graph, tested without that key statement and it works so I'll drop that from the php (data coming in that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick

```
$phpArray = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'Basic Planners',
        'values'=> array(
            array('x' => 'YourPhone', 'y' => 150),
            array('x' => 'Universe X3', 'y' => 300),
            array('x' => 'ePhone 74s', 'y' => 1500),
            array('x' => 'NextUs', 'y' => 50),
            array('x' => 'Humanoid', 'y' => 500),
        )
    ),
    /* and so on... */
);

echo json_encode($phpArray);
```

Comment: Thanks dude! I kept getting close but screwing up. I'm more of a designer, CSS and jQuery guy than server side.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

For the JSON Objects use `array("key" => value, ...)`

for the JSON Arrays use `array(arg0, arg1, arg2, ...)`

Then just nest these various groupings. This should output the desired JSON.